# Is there a way to force cypress to open in same tab instead of another tab

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I know one of Cypress' trade-offs is testing on multiple tabs. However, our website default to opening another tab. Can I force Cypress to open on same tab to continue my tests?
I have this code below but still opens a new tab:

```
cy.get(element).invoke('attr', 'target', ' _self').click()
```

I remember finding it somewhere that it can be done but my 1am brain is unable to find it via google search.
I also found this on the Cypress documentation but it may not be relevant to my case as I would need to do multiple assertions on that new page which is logged on via SSO:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#Function-with-Arguments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would try to invoke the `href` attr from yielded subject and `cy.visit()`(which means the cypress opens it in the same app tab), like:

```
cy.get(element).invoke('attr', 'href').then(myLink => {
    cy.visit(myLink);
})
```

Comment: This worked as it opens on same tab. Unfortunately, a bummer that it's not same super-domain even if it it is redirected via SSO (which is accepted in Cypress) but does not work in this case - I will deal with that separately I guess.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
cy.get(element).invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use

```
describe('describe', () => {
  let myLink: string

  it('Get response body', () => {
    cy.intercept('https://prod.cypress.io/users').as('users')
    cy.get(element).click().wait('@users')
      .then(res => {
        myLink = res.response.body.url
      })
  })

  it('Go to myLink', () => {
    cy.visit(myLink)
  })
})
```